# Open-save dialog automatically opens the folder which is currently opened in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, autohotkey, windows-explorer

I want to realize a program which works in this way:
I have a folder opened in Windows Explorer. I'm working in a program and I want to save my work. I open the Open/save dialog and I'd like to have a shortcut to automatically jump to the folder which is currently opened in Windows Explorer.

I think AutoHotKey should do the trick but I don't know how to go on.
Perhaps the best solution is:

- set a shortcut to save the currently active folder in Windows Explorer
- set another shortcut which make the currently opened open-save dialog jump to the saved directory.

Is it possible to realize that in AHK? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example (using a new notepad document):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad

    F1::
        explorer_path := "" ; empty variable
        IfWinNotExist ahk_class CabinetWClass ; explorer
            return  ; do nothing
        ; otherwise:
        ; https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?p=28751#p28751
        ; get the path of the first explorer window:
        for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        {
            try explorer_path := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
                    break
        }
        ; MsgBox, %explorer_path%
        Send, ^s ; save the new document
        ; wait for the Save As window and activate it
        WinWait, Save As ahk_class #32770
        WinActivate, Save As ahk_class #32770
        WinWaitActive, Save As ahk_class #32770
        ; open the folder "explorer_path" in Save As
        SendInput, %explorer_path%
        Sleep, 300
        Send, {Enter}
    return

#IfWinActive
```